# Trying to find the set of unique representatives for the geodesics in the group $\langle a,t \mid ata^{-2}t^2a^{-2}tat^{-4}\rangle$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, group-presentation, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

I am studying the conjugacy growth of the groups, and I encountered the following group:
$$G=\langle a,t \mid ata^{-2}t^2a^{-2}tat^{-4}\rangle$$

Thanks to Derek for pointing out that $G$ is an infinite hyperbolic group.

**Question:** Given a word in $\{a^{\pm 1}, t^{\pm 1}\}$, is there a way to check whether this word is a geodesic or not? (Or are there certain criteria for a word to be a geodesic)

Any ideas/references would be really appreciated.

Comment: This is certainly not a polycyclic group. It is an infinite hyperbolic group, and its geodesic words form a regular language.

Comment: Thank you @DerekHolt. In this case, the geodesic words form a regular language, is there a way to tell if two distinct geodesic words represent the same element? (I am trying to count the number of elements inside the ball of radius $n$, I wanted to know how many times I overcount an element.)

Comment: With a hyperbolic group you can reduce words to normal form, the so-called shortlex geodesic words. You can construct a finite state automaton accepting these words, and use that to compute the growth function, which tells you how many group elements are in the ball of radius $n$. You can do that for example using the KBMAG package in GAP, or in Magma.